# How to specify a memory area in Actual Hardware i.e. STM32F103RB

Tags: memory-management, stm32, access-violation, keil

In Keil uvision I can define a memory region by using MAP command.

> MAP 0x3FFFFB44,0x3FFFFFF8 read write

OR

I could use the Memory Map dialog from Keil "Debug" dropdown, specifying memory areas for data storage and program execution.

[image]

However, what should I do to specify the memory region in actual hardware (in my case STM32F103RB)?

Is there a way to specify a memory region in STM32 ST-LINK Utility software before burning code in my stm32 microcontroller?

**NOTE:**
I want to be able to read/write in a memory region from 0x3FFFFB44,0x3FFFFFF8 which is inaccessible. Everything works fine in Keil Simulator after I add this  memory region range in Memory Map dialog. What should I do to be able to access this region in actual hardware?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This region is not available on the real device.

If you had a look at the memory map from the datasheet you could see that the region is "reserved". If you want to select working region, please look at complete MemoryMap for your device.

[image: Memory Map]

Normally the area starting at

0x08000000 -> flash

0x20000000 -> sram

are available. The exact size of your device depends on your exact device.